# Add and Delete DSN/ODBC VBA in Excel with user name and password

Tags: excel, odbc, dsn, vba

I VBA code I set up to pull data from a parameter Access BD query. Problem is I have user permission to the SQL database set up through DSN ODBC but the other users don't. So I need to add a DSN connection with my user name and password then delete it after the codes finishes.... Here is what I have I really hope you guys can help.. Or i'll take any other suggestions on how to make it work. I'm using Excel pulling data from an Access DB that is pulling from a SQL server.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset

'Step 2: Identify the database and query
Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase _
("\\prd\ZipCode_Tools.accdb")
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("Query Zip Code & Market Seg")

'Step 3: Define the Parameters
With MyQueryDef
.Parameters("[Enter ZipCode]") = Range("D2").Value
.Parameters("[Enter Market Seg]") = Range("D3").Value
End With

'Step 4: Open the query
Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset

'Step 5: Clear previous contents
Sheets("MySheet").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:F10000").ClearContents

'Step 6: Copy the recordset to Excel
ActiveSheet.Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset

'Step 7: Add column heading names to the spreadsheet
'For i = 1 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count
'ActiveSheet.Cells(5, i).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name
'Next i

' MsgBox "Your Query has been Run"

End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be possible to write the sub to provide your credentials in your Personal.xlsb and have this button call that application, with error trapping to exit if your sub can not be found, i.e. someone else tries to run it? Call it with Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!CredentialsSubName".